# Active MQ - able to connect to other machine MySQL but not local machine MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, activemq-classic

I'm in a corporate network and using ActiveMQ in our project. I'm trying to persist data on MySQL instead of the default KahaDB and following the guide at [ActiveMQ home page](https://activemq.apache.org/how-to-configure-a-new-database)

the connection properties looks like this:

```
    <bean id="mysql-ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">  
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>  
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/activemq"/>  
        <property name="username" value="root"/>  
        <property name="password" value="123456"/>  
        <property name="poolPreparedStatements" value="true"/>  
    </bean>
```

When I starts the active mq server via bin/win64/wrapper.exe, I received "Communication link failure":

```
2020-09-21 14:56:36,983 | WARN  | Could not get JDBC connection: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 523 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 515 milliseconds ago.) | org.apache.activemq.store.jdbc.JDBCPersistenceAdapter | WrapperSimpleAppMain
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 523 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 515 milliseconds ago.)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
...

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
    ...
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:187)
```

I noticed that there's still some 'connection' since there were packets sent and received. The activemq server couldn't start nonetheless.

When I changed the connection properties to our staging server's ip address however, activemq started successfully.

I created a snippet to try connecting to the local db using the same connection properties and no error is thrown:

```
public class ConnectionTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (
         BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource()) {
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/activemq");
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            dataSource.setUsername("activemq");
            dataSource.setPassword("");
            dataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);
            Connection conn = dataSource.getConnection();
            conn.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In my snippet I'm using **mysql-connector-java.5.1.49.jar** and **common-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar**. These 2 jars are also in activemq/lib/optional

I tried 127.0.0.1, localhost, and my PC's IP address. None worked

What other solution could I try to have active mq use my local database?
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm no expert on MySQL, but it looks as if the exception you're getting results from a failed SSL handshake. Do you expect the MySQL server to be using SSL? If so, have you imported the relevant SSL certificates from the database into the broker? If the problem _is_ SSL-related, then running the broker with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl` will probably shed some light on what is going wrong. But do you expect the communication to be encrypted? If you don't, perhaps there's some configuration on MySQL that needs to be changed?

Comment: @KevinBoone thank you very much! I disabled SSL on my local MySQL and active MQ broker started successfully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Kevin Boone for pointing out the issue with SSL. I added in my ***my.ini*** file the following:

```
ssl=0
```

then restarted mysql service. Now my activeMQ broker could connect to the local db.